# How to initialize and fill an IVector with TimeSpan-Elements in a C++ UWP project?

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, iterable

I'm trying to take screenshots from an existing video in a defined time interval in an C++/CX UWP project. My idea was to use the function "GetThumbnailsAsync" from the [MediaComposition Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition):

```
    create_task(MediaClip::CreateFromFileAsync(this->last_video)).then([this](MediaClip^ clip )
{
    // Create a MediaComposition containing the clip and set it on the MediaElement.
    MediaComposition^ composition = ref new MediaComposition();
    composition->Clips->Append(clip);

    TimeSpan ts;
    ts.Duration = 1000;

    IVector<TimeSpan>^ i_ts_vector;
    //TODO

    create_task(composition->GetThumbnailsAsync(is_ts_vector, 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision::NearestFrame)).then([this, clip, composition](IVectorView<ImageStream^>^ imageStream)
    {
        //TODO
    });
});
```

last_video is a StorageFile with the video path.

This doesn't work because i_ts_vector is not initialized and is still NULL. I already tried things like:

```
IVector<TimeSpan>^ i_ts_vector = ref new Vector<TimeSpan>();
```

This works with int-vectors, but not with TimeSpan-vectors. It gives a compiler error:

> Error  C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How can I initialize and fill an IVector with TimeSpan-Elements? Or is there a better way to take screenshots?

Corono

Comment: Pretty sure you can use `auto i_ts_vector = ref new Vector<TimeSpan>();`.

Comment: `auto i_ts_vector = ref new Vector<TimeSpan>();` gives the same error: 
_Error C2678 binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan' (or there is no acceptable conversion)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that (Ref. [Value types in Vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/collections-c-cx#value-types-in-vector))

> Any element to be stored in a [Platform::Collections::Vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-collections-vector-class) must support equality comparison, either implicitly or by using a custom [std::equal_to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/equal-to-struct) comparator that you provide. All reference types and all scalar types implicitly support equality comparisons. For non-scalar value types such as [Windows::Foundation::DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.datetime.aspx), or for custom comparisons—for example, `objA->UniqueID == objB->UniqueID—you` must provide a custom function object.

[Time​Span Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.TimeSpan) is also one of the non-scalar value types that do not have the equality operation (`operator==`). So you got `Error C2678`. To slove this problem, you can provide a custom functor like the following:

```
struct MyEqual : public std::binary_function<const TimeSpan, const TimeSpan, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const TimeSpan& _Left, const TimeSpan& _Right) const
    {
        return _Left.Duration == _Right.Duration;
    }
};
```

And then use it in [Platform::Collections::Vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-collections-vector-class) like:

```
IVector<TimeSpan>^ i_ts_vector = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<TimeSpan, MyEqual>();
```